# Deindex a site through Google Search Console without access to the site's server to make changes?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, noindex

Is there an option in GSC to exclude the whole GSC property (all URLs of it) from indexing?

Implementing `noindex` isn't feasible.  I don't have access to the server to make changes.  I can't add a meta tag nor the x-robots header.  There are multiple URLs, so manual deindexing one URL at a time isn't feasible either.

**Scenario**: Suddenly was the whole staging server is getting indexed, around 1k URLs.  It is special subdomain like `www123`. Metadata, server setup (nginx conf) and robots are managed by IT, my contact partner from the in-house team has no access to all these resources and his Jira tickets for IT have very low priority.

I'm searching for a possible way to deindex the staging site, without using the usual methods which involve modifying the site.

Comment: See also [No index for an entire site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117152/no-index-for-an-entire-site) which suggest the meta tag and x-robots header

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the single option from the thread you linked, which could come into question, is securing the subdomain with login. But, this option isn't feasable too, because of lack of access to the server configuration. If an access to nginx would be possible, the best possible option would be accessible - deindexing with x-robots. But, as I said, this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Can Submit a Removal Request

Submitting will remove URLs for 6 months, this will buy you some time until you're able to put a permanent solution in place.
[image: Google Search Console Removals tool]

In your case, you might find the prefix option useful. The turnaround is generally very quick, at least in my experience.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats what I found in the meanwhile too - seems to be the only more or less durable option. What would you use as prefix? Just a slash or subdomain name like `www123`?

Comment: @Evgeniy I'd go the www123 route